# Isn't Redis supposed to cache db entries?

Tags: mysql, nginx, redis, memcached, mariadb

My server is Debian 9.0. It has SSD HDD with 32 of RAM. and i7 processor with 4 (8) cores.  I have 4 websites. 2 of them are very small and two large. The large databases (mysql) are about 120 + 60 MB in size. My webserver is nginx, also using varnish.

Well, i want to learn about linux so i started reading articles about tuning nginx, mysql, php-fpm etc. I was tuning mysql, installed mysqltuner. It advised me to set "query_cache_size" and "query_cache_type" to 0 which means disabling the cache..

I did. However my sites become really slower. My 680 Kb web page was loading in 700 ms but after disabling the query_cache, the speed decreased to almost 1,5 seconds. It was interesting. I set the query_cache_size back to 128M. So the speed was restored. I kept reading more about setting query_cache and read the article of Zaitsev (in percona.com) where he states that using a large cache is problematic and he says at the end of his article: " In many cases you may want to disable query cache at all and use external cache such as memcached which does not have this problem."

https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/03/23/beware-large-query_cache-sizes/

So, i installed REDIS (which they say is better than memcached and does things better). I installed it, i also installed the wordpress plugin for redis. i monitor redis and it works very fine. However two things happen:

1) Redis didnt improve my site speed. Its the same. No difference. Perhaps its because my web pages are very small (700 kb at most) and my databases are small also.

2) When i disable mysql query cache, my WEB SITE gets very slow again.

So isnt redis supposed to cache all DB entries and use them much faster than mysql? How come my webpage speed decreases when i disable query cache of mysql?

Comment: Redis is an open source (BSD licensed), in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker...AFAIK it is suposed to be used as a data store cache, in order to avoid unnecesary lookups to the database....with that in mind, you need to implement the communication with your redis layer and then implement in your code a cache pattern, like cache aside...is not that simple like installing redis and hope that it works...I think that if you need to cache another stuff, like static files or content, you better install apache OpCache and then run your `benchmark` again..

Comment: Is there any chance you will post the text results of mysqltuner report to eliminate may of the questions we all have about your installation?  And while your are posting critical information my.cnf/ini would be helpful.

Comment: [client-server]
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve

query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_min_res_unit=1k

key_buffer_size=128M

tmp_table_size=1G
max_heap_table_size=1G

Comment: table_open_cache=5000

innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
innodb_log_file_size=48M

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
sync_binlog=0

innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_checksum_algorithm=crc32

innodb_io_capacity=200
innodb_io_capacity_max=400

innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown=on
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=on

Answer (score 0):

I agree that 700ms is too long.  Properly designed, you should be able to execute a hundred MySQL queries in that time; sounds like you aren't?

I agree that a large Query cache is usually unwise:

- It takes away RAM from other caching.
- *Every* modification to a table cause purging of *all* entries in the QC for that table.  If a table is changing often, you suffer overhead for that purging, while getting little or no benefit from caching.

You have a modest sized database -- under 1GB for everything?  With 32 GB of RAM, you should be able to cache all the data and indexes all the time.  So, slowdowns will be in poor indexing and/or poor query formulation.

I hope you are using InnoDB, not MyISAM.  With InnoDB, you need to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to no more than 70% of *available* RAM.  You have several products running in the 32G??  So, I won't say 70% of 32.  (Note: Swapping is terrible for performance.)  Since you have so little data, perhaps 2G would be a good setting?

Let's see the queries in your "too slow" web page.  Also, let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  Do you know about "composite" indexes?  Do you know not to hide indexed columns in function calls?

Perhaps my [*cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) can help you from here.  If you are using WP, it includes a section on how to speed up `wp_postmeta`.  If you need more help, start another Question with the slowest query, its `EXPLAIN`, and its schema.

Comment: No no, my total web site is loaded in 700 ms.. (All the images, google adsense scripts, text, etc etc etc). My Database is about 200 MB. Btw how come innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size is not shown ine "SHOW VARIABLES Like '%innodb%'; ?

Comment: @LinuxNewbie - What version of MySQL are you running?  `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` was introduced in 5.7.5.

Comment: @LinuxNewbie - What does "total web site loaded" mean?  A web site is usually loaded one page at a time.  How many images?  How big?  Are they bigger, but then shrunk as they are displayed?

Comment: 700 ms is faster than %90 of all the sites (according to tools.pingdom). 700 ms is not the load time of database query but load time of the "page".

Comment: Like www.example.com/how-to-buy.html

Comment: I'm getting lost.  What is the question?  You mentioned a lot of db-related numbers.  You implied that 800 (1500-700) ms was caused by the caching in the db or redis.  My general opinion is not to put a cache (eg, Redis) in front of another cache (the caching in MySQL).

Comment: No... When my i enabled query_cache my web site page is loaded in 700 ms... However when i disable the query_cache, its loaded in 1,5 seconds.

So i installed redis, disabled the query_cache, but redis does NOT cache mysql (instead of query_cache).. Thats the question. How could i make it so, redis caches mysql queries instead of query cache?

Comment: Well, i have mariadb 10.1, can i simply convert myisam tables to innodb via phpmyadmin? Any problems might happen?

Comment: @LinuxNewbie - The likely issues in the conversion are covered [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) .

Comment: Yes i read that. However its a bit too hard for me to understand at this level. In one of the articles i read about converting myisam to innodb, it says: "Ensure you are running MySQL 5.6.4 or higher otherwise you might run into issues where full-text indexing is not supported yet by InnoDB."

Im running MariaDB 10.1.26 which fully supports full-text-indexing for innodb. So i shouldnt have a problem right?

Comment: NP.  If you are not using any `FULLTEXT` indexes, "Ensure..." is irrelevant.  "10.1.26 fully supports...", so, again, the "Ensure..." is irrelevant.

Comment: If only i knew im using FULL-TEXT indexes or not. I dont even know that. I converted all the myisma tables to innodb and they are working fine for now.

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)` indicates `FULLTEXT` is in use.